# How to run pandas concat in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I would like to do two merge files procedure in parallel through multiprocessing. Each of them merge tens of files into one. What is the correct syntax to write it?

Without multi processing it was running OK

```
tripnames = [filename for filename in os.listdir(paths.outPath) if filename.startswith("trips")]
odnames = [filename for filename in os.listdir(paths.outPath) if filename.startswith("workOD")]

combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(paths.outPath + f) for f in tripnames])
combinedOD_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(paths.outPath + f) for f in odnames])

combined_csv.to_csv( paths.outPath + "trips.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
combinedOD_csv.to_csv( paths.outPath + "workOD.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

With multiprocessing

```
tripnames = [filename for filename in os.listdir(paths.outPath) if filename.startswith("trips")]
odnames = [filename for filename in os.listdir(paths.outPath) if filename.startswith("workOD")]
combined_csv = Process(target=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(paths.outPath + f) for f in tripnames]))
combinedOD_csv = Process(target=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(paths.outPath + f) for f in odnames]))
combined_csv.start()
combinedOD_csv.start()
combined_csv.join()
combinedOD_csv.join()            
exe_tripMerge = Process(target=combined_csv.to_csv(paths.outPath + "trips.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig'))
exe_workODMege = Process(target=combinedOD_csv.to_csv(paths.outPath + "workOD.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig'))
exe_tripMerge.start()
exe_workODMege.start()
exe_tripMerge.join()
exe_workODMege.join()
```

The error I got is

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "runrtm.py", line 157, in <module>
    main()
File "runrtm.py", line 112, in main
    combined_csv = Process(target=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(paths.outPath + f) for f in tripnames]))
AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

I am looking for the right syntax. Thanks in advance.